# podman play kubernetes: Volume mount database-data-volume specified for container but not configured in volumes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, podman

I have a kubernetes pod configuration with a named volume and want to run it via `podman play kube` which fails for an unknown reason:

`podman play kube kubernetes.yml`:

```
Error: kubernetes.yml: Volume mount database-data-volume specified for container but not configured in volumes
```

---

The error indicates that the volume does not exist, but it's there:

```
> podman volume list

DRIVER      VOLUME NAME
local       database-data-volume
```

`kubernetes.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  containers:
  ...
  - image: it.impl/h2-database:2.1.214-0
    name: database
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8082
        hostPort: 8082
      - containerPort: 9092
        hostPort: 9092
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/h2-database/data
        name: database-data-volume
  volumes:
    - persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: database-data-volume
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `volume` is missing a name (this would fail on Kubernetes as well). The `volumes` section maps a volume name to some sort of volume definition; when you write:

```
  volumes:
    - persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: database-data-volume
```

You have a volume definition but no volume name. You need:

```
  volumes:
    - name: database-data-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: database-data-volume
```